# Nested divs should resize according to the divs inside them, but they dont

Tags: html, css

I do not understand why the rightcontent and leftcontent divs do not stay in the centerbody div when the number of "< p>"s is increased.

I have attached a picture of what happens.
[The dots should stay inside the white space. And the white space should auto resize according to the length of the content. Shouldnt it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RbPZ.png)

```
<html>

  <style media="screen" type="text/css">

    body {
        background-color: #efefef;
    }

    h1 {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    p {
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #centerbody {   /*this is the style of the main body white box */
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0,      0, 0.19);
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 100px 50px 100px 50px;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #rightContent {
        float:right;
        width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #leftContent {
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

  </style>

  <body>

    <div id="centerbody">

      <div id="rightContent">
          <p>.</p>
          <p>.</p>
          <p>.</p>
          <p>.</p>
          <p>.</p>
          <p>.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="leftContent">
          right side stuff
      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think it's because your parent div actually does not has a specific width.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ may help

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things:

- Float #centerbody left or right.
- Set #centerbody to display:inline-block
- Use the "clear" trick, by having an empty DIV after your floating DIVs that has "clear:both"

To explain: a floating element's height is not added to its container. Floating elements DO listen to the height of other floating elements. So by setting your parent container to float, or inline-block, you're letting it take into account its child elements' heights.

The clear trick is an old move if the other two options aren't viable for the rest of your project, as it injects a normal block element into the container, working as a signal for the container on where the "end " of the container should be.

Comment: that made centerbody small.
and even if i set the width to 100%, the white space just extends off screen, it gets that large.

Comment: Well, there's more to your problem than just the height not adapting, but what wasn't your question. You have not set a width on your container. A floating or inline-block element fits to its content. Set the width that you want on the container.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can set your parent container as a flex box and give your parent an explicit width

```css
body {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#centerbody {   /*this is the style of the main body white box */
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 100px 50px 100px 50px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#rightContent {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#leftContent {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="centerbody">
    
    <div id="leftContent">
        <p>
        hello
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContent">
        right side stuff
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
        <p>.</p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: you are placing his right content on left and vice versa

Comment: @HassanZia woops, the code is right, just put the "right text" in the left section...

Comment: still it's not it buddy

Comment: ah bud :) why don't you see that **right side stuff** is actually on left side

Answer (score 0):

Your content is coming out of the `div`'s that are being `float`ed.
You probably don't know what the float has an impact on it's parent.
You should definitely read the following article [All About Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Note: It's one of the most important concepts in CSS(another one is `position`ing) so I recommend you to read the mentioned article.

If you want a quick answer then do this:

```
{parent-div}:before, {parent-div}:after{
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block; //or inline-block
}
```

What `clear` and `content` do is explained well in the mentioned article.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Check the Edit history to get a clear idea**

maybe this is what you are looking for

```css
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#centerbody {   /*this is the style of the main body white box */
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0,      0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 100px 50px 100px 50px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;

}

#rightContent {
  float:right;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#leftContent {
  line-height: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#empty{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="centerbody">

  <div id="leftContent">
    right side stuff
  </div>

  <div id="rightContent">
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
    <p>.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="empty"></div>



</div>
```